React: Excluding previously matched animals from an array without breaking the app
I'm building a fast-paced game where the user collects animals through matching. The game works as follows: The user is presented with 2 pictures of 2 animals, and they must cycle through the pictures by pressing 2 buttons, one that changes the top picture and one that changes the bottom. When the top picture and bottom picture match, that animal is collected and put in the user's bestiary.
You can try it here: https://animal-snipet.web.app/
I'm trying to filter data from animalData that corresponds with the user's caught animals so that these animals don't show up in the next game. Ideally, the code snippet below would push a filtered array that consists of animals the user hasn't caught yet, and then, in the next game, animal data would be assigned to this new array. All my attempts at coding this have resulted in the top and bottom indexes rapidly switching through all the pictures and breaking my app.
Here are the relevant code snippets
//The code that executes whenever a button is clicked. There's an identical function named voteTop that mirros what voteBottom does.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [animalData, setAnimalData] = useState(["Dog", "Cat", "Bird"]); // Sample data
  const [matchedAnimals, setMatchedAnimals] = useState([]);
  
  // Simulating vote function
  const vote = () => {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * animalData.length);
    const matchedAnimal = animalData[randomIndex];
    setMatchedAnimals(prevMatchedAnimals => [...prevMatchedAnimals, matchedAnimal]);
    setAnimalData(prevAnimalData => prevAnimalData.filter((_, index) => index !== randomIndex));
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Animal Data</h2>
      <ul>
        {animalData.map((animal, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{animal}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <button onClick={vote}>Vote</button>
      <h2>Matched Animals</h2>
      <ul>
        {matchedAnimals.map((animal, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{animal}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

  

Firebase Setup:
I'm using Firebase to store the animal data and matched animals. Here's how the data is structured:

animalData array: stored in the Firebase Realtime Database under the "unclaimed" node.
matchedAnimals array: stored in the Firebase Realtime Database under the "matchedAnimals" node.

I'm using the Firebase SDK to read and write data to these nodes.
Expected behavior:
After a game ends, the previously matched animals should be filtered out from the animalData array, so that the next game starts with a fresh set of animals.

What have you tried already on your own as far as removing values from the animalData array when there is a match? What does getNextIndex do when it computes a new target index? Please [edit] to clarify what the specific issue or problem is and include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with.

@DrewReese
I've made a unique array, MatchedAnimals, for the user that keeps track of all previously caught animals through filtering animals in the animalData array.
I've tried the same method, but instead of putting this block of code inside the voteTop/voteBottom functions, I inserted it outside so it would update after the game ends.
getNextIndex randomly picks an index from animalData and returns newIndex whenever it's called by either vote function.

Can you [edit] to provide a complete [mcve] of the app/component code instead of just this single "vote bottom" handler?

Sorry, new to this. I think I put a decent mre.

This updated code example appears to work correctly; the value at the random index is removed from one array and appended to the other. This updated code also appears to be quite different from your previous code example since now there's only 1 array of animals displayed and one button.

Instead of trying to do all the work in a button's onClick handler that is effectively duplicated across two vote button's callbacks, I suggest adding some React state that holds the randomly generated indices and the button callbacks just update these state. Move the logic to test for matches between button/voting indices into a useEffect hook.
Example:
const [randIndex1, setRandIndex1] = useState(() => getRandIndex(animalData));
const [randIndex2, setRandIndex2] = useState(() => getRandIndex(animalData));

useEffect(() => {
  // Check if there are animals to match, and that the voted indices match
  if (animalData.length && randIndex1 === randIndex2) {
    const matched = animalData[randIndex1];

    // Remove the matched animal from the animals array
    const nextAnimals = animalData.toSpliced(randIndex1, 1);
    setAnimalData(nextAnimals);

    // Append matched animal to the matched animals array
    setMatchedAnimals((matchedAnimals) => matchedAnimals.concat(matched));

    // Recompute two new random array indices to select
    // new random animals to match for the next round
    setRandIndex1(getRandIndex(nextAnimals));
    setRandIndex2(getRandIndex(nextAnimals));
  }
}, [animalData, randIndex1, randIndex2]);

const vote1Handler = () => setRandIndex1(getRandIndex(animalData));
const vote2Handler = () => setRandIndex2(getRandIndex(animalData));

Full Demo:


const data = ["Dog", "Cat", "Bird", "Pig", "Shark", "Worm", "Eagle", "Lion"];

const getRandIndex = (arr) => Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);

function App() {
  const [animalData, setAnimalData] = React.useState(data);
  const [matchedAnimals, setMatchedAnimals] = React.useState([]);

  const [randIndex1, setRandIndex1] = React.useState(() => getRandIndex(animalData));
  const [randIndex2, setRandIndex2] = React.useState(() => getRandIndex(animalData));

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (animalData.length && randIndex1 === randIndex2) {
      const matched = animalData[randIndex1];
      const nextAnimals = animalData.toSpliced(randIndex1, 1);
      setAnimalData(nextAnimals);
      setMatchedAnimals((matchedAnimals) => matchedAnimals.concat(matched));
      setRandIndex1(getRandIndex(nextAnimals));
      setRandIndex2(getRandIndex(nextAnimals));
    }
  }, [animalData, randIndex1, randIndex2]);

  const vote1Handler = () => setRandIndex1(getRandIndex(animalData));
  const vote2Handler = () => setRandIndex2(getRandIndex(animalData));

  const reset = () => {
    setAnimalData(data);
    setMatchedAnimals([]);
    setRandIndex1(getRandIndex(data));
    setRandIndex2(getRandIndex(data));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Animal Data</h2>
      <div>{animalData.join(", ")}</div>

      {animalData.length ? (
        <div className="vote-container">
          <button type="button" onClick={vote1Handler}>
            {animalData[randIndex1]}
          </button>
          <button type="button" onClick={vote2Handler}>
            {animalData[randIndex2]}
          </button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <button type="button" onClick={reset}>
          Reset
        </button>
      )}

      <h2>Matched Animals</h2>
      <div>{matchedAnimals.join(", ")}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.vote-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />



